# What is the difference between cast() and typecast() commands in Matlab

Tags: matlab, casting

Executing these commands in matlab workspace

```
a = 10
b = cast(a,'uint8')
c = typecast(a,'uint8')
```

while I look for the values of b and c I get

> b =  10
>
> c =  0    0    0    0    0    0   36   64

Also `whos('b')` and `whos('c')` returns `uint8`

Comment: The 8 numbers that `typecast` returns is the internal representation of the `double` value; `cast` returns the result of the usual type conversion.

Answer (score 4):

The answer comes from the [documentation of `typecast`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html):

> **typecast** is different from the MATLAB® cast function in that it **does
>   not alter the input data**. typecast always returns the same number of
>   bytes in the output Y as were in the input X. For example, casting the
>   16-bit integer 1000 to uint8 with typecast returns the full 16 bits in
>   two 8-bit segments (3 and 232) thus keeping its original value (3*256
>   + 232 = 1000). The cast function, on the other hand, truncates the input value to 255.